# WiX give write permission

Tags: wix, windows-services, windows-installer, sql-server-ce

I need to give permission to a `LocalSystem` windows service installed with WIX to write a SQL Server CE file to `CommonAppDataFolder`. I'm using:

```
<Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
    <Directory Id="CompanyNameDataFolder" Name="!(loc.CompanyName)">
        <Directory Id="AppFolder" Name="!(loc.FolderName)" >
            <Component Id="DataDirectory" Guid="*">
                <CreateFolder>
                    <utils:PermissionEx User="[WIX_ACCOUNT_LOCALSYSTEM]" GenericAll="yes" 
                                        ChangePermission="yes" />
                </CreateFolder>
            </Component>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

But it's not doing the trick. I am also trying this inside the service install, but no luck.

```
<utils:PermissionEx User="[WIX_ACCOUNT_LOCALSYSTEM]" GenericAll="yes" />
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really the core of my field, but in the interest of helping out, let us try: doesn't **`LocalSystem`** pretty much have "*access all areas*" on a normal computer? (with a few minor exceptions). There must be something else wrong? What do the logs say? What does the event viewer report?

Maybe see if some of these answers are illuminating?:

- [SQL Compact Edition 3.5 - Access to the database file is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647663/sql-compact-edition-3-5-access-to-the-database-file-is-not-allowed)
- [Cannot deploy application with SQLce datbase.sdf file. says file path is wrong?!](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0982ef87-4a1e-4822-92be-1b9d9ff07bbc/cannot-deploy-application-with-sqlce-datbasesdf-file-says-file-path-is-wrong?forum=sqlce)
- [Using the Microsoft Desktop Stack – Part 1: Setting up SQL Compact 4.0 for Private Deployment](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/180734/Using-the-Microsoft-Desktop-Stack-Part-Setting-u)

Comment: Thank you! Although that was not the reason for my problem very helpful tips. What I was doing wrong was changing the name of my exe file, so the exe and config were different in name and was not loading the configuration. So, no DB. I very much appreciate the help.